# Refactor useEffect hook with useCallback - React

Tags: reactjs

Dashboard component:

```
const [breadcrumbs, setBreadcrumbs] = useState<Crumb[]>([]);

const handleCrumbs = (data: Crumb[]) => {
  setBreadcrumbs(data);
};

return (
  <>
    <Breadcrumbs crumbsArray={breadcrumbs} />
    <Route
      path={`${path}/partners`}
      render={() => <Partners crumbs={handleCrumbs} />}
    />
  </>
);
```

Partners component:

```
const Partners: React.FC<any> = ({ crumbs }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    crumbs(arr);
  }, []);
}
```

There i'm getting an error:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'crumbs'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'crumbs' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

How can i refactor this with useCallback? I can just disable eslint error and everything would work as expected, but how to do that in a "right way"?

Logic behind this, is when Partners component is mounted, i'm setting breadcrumb items in the parent component - Dashboard.

**UPDATE 1**

Dashboard:

```
const handleCrumbs = useCallback((data: Crumb[]) => {
  setBreadcrumbs(data);
}, []);
```

Partners:

```
const Partners: React.FC<any> = ({ crumbs }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    crumbs(arr);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `handleCrumbs` in `useCallback` and then it will be safe to add `crumbs` to the dependencies array because the reference will never change.

without `useCallback` it will end up in an infinite loop because on every re-render the reference of `crumbs` will change

Dashboard

```js
const handleCrumbs = useCallback((data: Crumb[]) => {
  setBreadcrumbs(data);
}, []);
```

Partners

```js
const Partners: React.FC<any> = ({ crumbs }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    crumbs(arr);
  }, [crumbs]);
}
```

Also, a lot of people prefer not to use `React.FC` and just type `children` explicitly if you need them, you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177)

Comment: Thanks, but your `useCallback()` with empty deps, would cause the same error, as `useEffect` with empty deps :) BTW, thanks for `React.FC` note, i've read before that many people aren't preferring to use it, but couldn't understand - why.

Comment: @AlexanderKim it doesn't produce the error. Have you tried the code ?

Comment: What error exactly? I have added `crumbs` as a dependency in `useEffect`

Comment: @AsafAviv, had an error in my code, now it doesn't complain about empty deps in `useCallback`, but i still have infinite loop with re-renders. Will update my question with what i have tried. I just forgot to add explicitly `[crumbs]` in useEffect deps, BUT isn't omitting deps at all automatically adds everything in the deps?

Comment: @AlexanderKim You didn't add `crumbs` as a dependency to `useEffect`, `useEffect` without a second argument will run on every re-render

Comment: @AsafAviv, thanks just read documentation again, i misunderstood it. Without a deps it would re-render after every complete render, basically it would just infinite loop without deps at all? Could you explain, please.

Comment: @AlexanderKim In practice, there is no use for a `useEffect` without a dependencies array because the effect will run on **every** re-render, you should not do any side effect inside of it that will queue up a re-render as this will result in an infinite loop. so always include exactly what you need inside of it and do some `if` checks if you need to prevent an infinite loop